# Kivy fails to find a Window provider after switching drivers

Tags: python, kivy, nvidia

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.5 and Kivy v1.9.2-dev0
When browsing through the settings, I've noticed that I'm not using the proprietary recommended driver from NVIDIA, but instead I'm using the open-source nouveau. So I thought that it would be best to switch. But when I did that, suddenly my Kivy application started failing. This is the log:

```
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.2-dev0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 193 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
egl_rpi - ImportError: cannot import name 'bcm'
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.lib.vidcore_lite import bcm, egl

sdl2 - RuntimeError: b'Could not create GL context: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 139, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 794, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 262, in create_window
    self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 142, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window (kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:2462)
  File "kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx", line 56, in kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die (kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.c:1556)

x11 - ImportError: No module named 'kivy.core.window.window_x11'
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

The application worked perfectly with nouveau, so what's the reason to this crash? Should I switch back to nouveau? Is there a way to make it work with NVIDIA drivers?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment but is this error fixed?

Comment: @Eddie Unfortunately, my PC didn't go well with the official NVIDIA driver and I fell back to nouveau, so I can't tell if your answer is correct. When future readers will rate your answer, I will accept it based on their experience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im using the official NVIDIA driver as well and it works perfectly fine on my machine. You are missing some library files I suppose. Did you get any errors installing the prerequisites for Kivy like Cython, PyGame, SDL2 etc?

**Answer updated**

If Im not mistaken, your previous installation of dependencies are not compatible with your new Graphics Driver. You are gonna have to install the dependencies again because sometimes the dependencies get installed and compiled slightly differently depending upon your current hardware, driver, Operating System configurations etc.

Sometimes restarting the computer helps as well particularly when (for whatever reason) the older demons are still running in the background even if the update is successful.

According to your trace back error, something (I don't know SDL2, PyGame or something) is unable to create a Window and Kivy doesn't have anything to render it's graphics.

If I were you, I would full uninstall all the global dependencies for Kivy, I would uninstall Kivy as well and use PyEnv (https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) to manage the local installation of the dependencies. Please remember PyEnv has it's own dependencies (https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems).

Comment: No, everything should be fine. As I mentioned, Kivy works flawlessly using the nouveau driver, so all the dependencies should be in place

Comment: Restarting the computer helped.